# Hide a toggle inside a toggle

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, toggle

How can I hide a toggle when there's another toggle and if the user show the one inside and you hide the one outside the one inside keeps there? It should be hidden too.

I was not clear so here is the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/hEusd/5/

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
if($(this).val()=="checking"){
    $(".open-box").toggle();
    if("none" == $(".open-box").css("display")) { 
        $(".box1").css("display", "none");
    }
}
});

$('.open-box').click(function() {
$(".box1").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Alright, I solved it again after you clarified. Welcome to StackOverflow by the way.

Comment: This isn't getting any clearer, could you draw an image (Paint will do) that describes the problem?

Comment: Ok on the new example: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/hEusd/5/ When you check the box it shows a link when you click on it, a new div appears. But when you uncheck the box the new div stills there.

Two guys already solved it but they skip the input's value: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/Jm4L6/

Comment: There's the 3rd one: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/Jm4L6/2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This solves it, and it's an easy fix: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/2PcWV/2

```
<input type="checkbox" value="checking">

<div class="box1">
    <a href="#" class="open-box">Show next box</a>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

**UPDATE:**

After you clarified, here is a new snippet: http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/Jm4L6/1

That is this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function () {
    if (this.checked) {
        $(".open-box").show();
    } else {
        $(".open-box").hide();
        $(".box1").hide();
    }
});

$('.open-box').click(function () {
    $(".box1").slideToggle();
});
```

With this HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox"> <a href="#" class="open-box">Show next box</a>

<div class="box1"></div>
```

It involves ideas talked about here: [How to check whether a checkbox is checked in jQuery?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/901712/check-checkbox-checked-property-using-jquery)

This third update ought to cover everything you asked:

http://jsfiddle.net/digitalextremist/Jm4L6/2/

Comment: I think I was not clear. Look at the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/hEusd/5/

Comment: I see what you want, I am updating my answer with a new code snippet and a link to what you're asking about.

Comment: It works well, but I need to use the input's value. How can I add it?

Comment: Did you uodate yout jsfiddle? I don't see any call to value="checking"

Comment: Yes, I updated the fiddle, but there is a problem with what you're asking. There is a line commented out which shows what I mean. The value attribute will always be 'checking' ... Whether it's hidden or showing. What you need to be checking is 'checked' ...

How do you want to use the value of the checkbox?

Comment: Wait, I see what you want. One second.

Answer (score 0):

In your jsfiddle, box2 isn't inside box1.  If you put it inside box1, then it will get hidden.  If you need to leave it outside, add something like this:

```
$('input[type="checkbox"]').click(function(){
    if($(this).val()=="checking"){
        $(".box1").toggle();
        if("none" == $(".box1").css("display")) { // ADD THIS IF BLOCK
            $(".box2").css("display", "none");
        }
    }
});

$('.open-box').click(function() {
    $(".box2").slideToggle();
});
```

Comment: Why not simply use `$(this).val()` ??

Comment: Wouldn't `if(!$(".box1").is(":visible")){` instead of `if("none" == $(".box1").css("display")) {` be simpler?

Comment: Updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/hEusd/5/ I think you almost answer my question. Thank you!

Comment: I see you changed the class names and made one an `<a>` tag, but the boxes still aren't nested.

Comment: Yes, the structure I put as example was not the best. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put both the boxes inside a container, and change it so that clicking the checkbox toggles the container div.

see example here: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/hEusd/3/)

I changed the HTML to put both boxes in a div like this:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="checking">
<div class="box-container">
    <div class="box1">
        <a href="#" class="open-box">Show next box</a>
    </div>
    <div class="box2"></div>
</div>
```

and changed the checkbox click event to toggle the container:

```
$(".box-container").toggle();
```

Comment: I was not clear with my question. Here is the updated example: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/hEusd/5/

Answer (score 0):

You shouldnt use `$(this).val()=="checking"` as it will always return `true` whether the checkbox is checked or not.

I would go with something like this :

http://jsfiddle.net/hEusd/12/

Comment: I just update the fiddle because my questions was not clear: http://jsfiddle.net/jalxob/hEusd/5/

Comment: Updated the fiddle to reflect your changes.

Comment: When you check the checkbox the .open-class and .box1 should be hide

Comment: You changes works I just think you forgot to call the value's input.